# Iterating over a list column of xml nodesets with purrr without flattening the results

Tags: r, xml, tidyverse, purrr, rvest

**Edit 2:** **Updated to take care of the problems from the dput output.**

I don't know why the dput output is not working, so here is a roundabout way of sharing the data.

A simple zip file of the data can be downloaded from here: [link to zip file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QQe4C0SRhZgUOJPzy66Xx5IdBwBAqxBm/view?usp=sharing)

The following code should then represent the data I was trying to share. Note that you will need to replace the path name for the downloaded zip file, and that the parse_file function will create a temporary directory:

```
## Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(XML)

## list files
list_paths <- list.files(path = "path_to_downloaded_zip_folder", pattern = ".xml", full.names = TRUE)
files <- list_paths %>% basename %>% path_ext_remove()

## set up temporary junk folder
junk <- tempdir("junk")

## functions

parse_file <- function(file) {
  file <- gsub("<c", "<w", file)
  file <- gsub("</c", "</w", file)
  xml <- xmlParse(file)
  saveXML(xml,paste0(junk,"/parse.xml"))
  xml <- read_xml(paste0(junk,"/parse.xml"))
  content <- xml %>% xml_nodes("div[level='1']")
  ### remove junk xml file
  unlink(paste0(junk,"/parse.xml"))
  ## in case no dim[level='1'] 
  if (length(content) == 0) {
    content <- xml %>%
      xml_nodes("div")
  }
  return(content)
}

parse_text <- function(content){
  ### get the text
  text<-content %>% xml_nodes("s") %>% html_text()
  return(text)
}


## create dat df
dat <- tibble(file = files, path = list_paths) %>%
  mutate(datasets =  map(path, ~read_file(.)),
content = map(datasets, ~parse_file(.))) %>% select(file , content)
```

This leaves a dataframe of list columns from xml data, with the content column containing lists of xml nodeset objects.

I would like to parse the nodesets in the content column to text, which can be done with the parse_text function above.

I can use `purrr::map` to iterate over the content column to get the text for each file...

```
dat %>% mutate(text = map(content, ~ parse_text(.) %>% set_names(file)))
```

... and retain the names of the file, but this ends up flattening the nodesets in the content column, and merging the text together.

What I'd really like to do is have a text column with the number of elements in each row representing the number of nodesets in the content column. That is, the text column for file **news_A84** should have one element (ideally named news_A84_01), and the text column row for file **news_A9P** should have two (named news_A9P_01 and news_A9P_02).

I have already got some code that goes about it with a `for` loop, but I was wondering whether it is possible to split up nodeset objects in this way with `purrr`?

The desired output of dat$text should look something like:

```
structure(list(text = list(news_A84 = list(news_A84_001 = c("Letters.", 
"By PETER STANFORD is right in maintaining (Weekend Guardian, November 4) that Graham Greene is not alone in calling himself a ‘Catholic agnostic’.", 
"An earlier thinker who declined to see any mutual contradiction between similar terms was Leslie Weatherhead, psychologist and cleric, who published his Creed of a Christian Agnostic.", 
"Weatherhead was honest enough to realise that there are many aspects of religion about which one has to remain uncertain, that is, agnostic.", 
"These ‘difficult’ areas will vary from one individual to another.", 
"As a self-confessed Christian agnostic he himself, however, was sure of a number of the major tenets of Christianity.", 
"His ‘creed’ claimed (in part): ‘I believe that God exists…", 
"I believe there is mind behind the universe…", "Such a mind must be love rather than hate…", 
"I believe in the divinity of Christ…", "I believe that sin is a grisly fact in the world…", 
"I believe that God's forgiveness is one of the most blessed and therapeutic experiences and that it is offered to all who seek it…", 
"I believe that our relationship with God is the most important thing in the world…", 
"I believe that each individual is precious to God.’", "Within this creed appear supportive rational arguments but also agnostic admissions, such as‘I can understand little about that mind’ and ‘I do not know what ‘divine’means’.", 
"I imagine that many honest people would sympathise with Weatherhead and happily echo his final paragraph: ‘All this gives me as much as I need, and seems to me the essential credo of Christianity.", 
"About the rest I am content to be agnostic.’", "Michael J.Smith.", 
"Southampton.", "FROM HIS Fifth Dimension article, Peter Stanford sounds even further burnt out than Graham Greene who continues capable of grim religious fun when opportunities arise.", 
"Indeed, Greene's latest revelations about his faith-non-faith appear quite knowingly hilarious.", 
"There's such sad unenthusiasm, on the other hand, about the way Stanford confuses personal doubt with the existence of mystery, as if one engenders the other, and, in doing so, must be assuaged by performance of some farcical rites.", 
"How boring!", "How pointless; precisely!", "Prayer, whether dramatised in a church or not, usually goes through futile-seeming passages.", 
"But even when extreme and prolonged, they have a strange tickle of meaning in them that becomes more of a mystery as faith grows.", 
"Olive Powell.", "Manchester.", "More letters Page 27")), news_A9P = list(
    news_A9P_001 = c("Snooker: Reynolds scales Davis peak.", 
    "By Clive Everton", "DEAN REYNOLDS, whitewashed 10-0 by Steve Davis in the final of the Rothmans Grand Prix in October, beat him 9-7 to reach the semi-finals of the Everest World Matchplay Championship at the Brentwood Centre late on Saturday.", 
    "The Grimsby left-hander's semi-final opponent on Wednesday will be Jimmy White, who won the last seven frames in a row to turn a 5-2 deficit into a 9-5 win over Doug Mountjoy.", 
    "Reynolds, 15th in the world rankings at the start of the season, has improved provisionally to eighth.", 
    "He had a gilt-edged opportunity to beat Stephen Hendry, so far the man of the season with four first prizes, in the Stormseal UK Open at Preston, but missed a simple pink when leading 22-0 in the deciding frame and did not have another shot.", 
    "Davis came to Brentwood a 16-12 loser to Hendry in the UK final and is going through a patch where he is making more unforced errors than usual.", 
    "‘There are certain times that are better than others,’ said Davis.", 
    "‘I'm a very good player.", "I can't be perfect.’", "Davis swept to 3-0 but missed the easiest of blues on the brink of 4-0.", 
    "Reynolds won that frame, the next on the pink, two more on the black, and the last of the afternoon to lead 5-3 at the interval.", 
    "He made it 6-3 with a 90 break, and after 52 minutes of tactical battling potted the pink for 7-3 and ran away with the next to go five up with six to play.", 
    "After this extraordinary eight-frame losing streak, Davis won four in a row to close to only 7-8, but two elementary mistakes in the following frame, failing to reach the yellow when rolling up behind it for a snooker, and failing to pot a red at close range along the top cushion, prefaced a run of 48 with which Reynolds secured his most notable scalp.", 
    "PAGE"), news_A9P_001 = c("Judo: Stevens justifies selection.", 
    "By Edward Ferrie", "THE British National Championships at Crystal Palace at the weekend once again saw Wolverhampton dominate the proceedings, with their fighters Elvis Gordon, at heavyweight, Densign White, at middleweight, Fitzroy Davies, at light-middleweight, and Owen Pinnock the bantamweight all taking gold medals.", 
    "There was, however, no Wolverhampton presence in the category which generated the greatest interest this weekend — the light-heavyweight.", 
    "Following the Olympic bronze medalist Denis Stewart's decision to retire from competition after a poor performance in the world championships in Belgrade, two months ago, the No.1 spot was up for grabs.", 
    "Stewart's bitter rival, the veteran Nicholas Kokataylo, the 33-year-old from Denton, in Manchester, was favourite for the gold medal, but a strong challenge was expected from newcomer to the weight, Ray Stevens, 26, of the London Budokwai.", 
    "The reigning Commonwealth middleweight champion Stevens was forced to move up to the heavier weight following a knee injury and a prolonged viral infection.", 
    "Stevens's superior speed and technique combined with superb fighting spirit carried him through to the final.", 
    "Kokataylo and Stevens was an all-action affair with the Manchester fighter scoring with a leg throw in the opening seconds which almost finished the bout.", 
    "A half point was awarded but Stevens fought his way back into the contest scoring with a spectacular sacrifice throw and almost arm locking the much taller and heavier Kokataylo.", 
    "Stevens, despite losing the bout, clearly did enough to justify his pre-event selection for the Commonwealth Games.", 
    "PAGE")))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Many thanks in advance!

In case it helps, here's my session info:

```
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] magrittr_1.5     zip_2.0.3        openxlsx_4.1.0.1
 [4] seas_0.5-2       MASS_7.3-51.4    tictoc_1.0      
 [7] rlang_0.4.10     fs_1.3.1         rvest_0.3.4     
[10] xml2_1.2.2       XML_3.98-1.20    forcats_0.4.0   
[13] stringr_1.4.0    dplyr_1.0.5      purrr_0.3.2     
[16] readr_1.3.1      tidyr_1.1.3      tibble_2.1.3    
[19] ggplot2_3.2.1    tidyverse_1.2.1  here_1.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` in `parse_text` function so that you get lists separately.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(XML)

parse_text <- function(content){
  text<- map(content, ~.x %>% xml_nodes("s") %>% html_text())
  return(text)
}
```

Then you can call these functions in `map2` and assign names.

```
tibble(file = files, path = list_paths) %>%
  mutate(datasets =  map2(path, file, function(x, y) x %>% read_file() %>% 
                                    parse_file() %>%  parse_text() %>%
                                    setNames(paste(y, seq_along(.), sep = '_'))))

#  file     path                datasets        
#  <chr>    <chr>               <list>          
#1 news_A84 ./dat//news_A84.xml <named list [1]>
#2 news_A9P ./dat//news_A9P.xml <named list [2]>
```

Comment: I had a feeling I needed to use map2, but couldn't get my head around it. Thanks!